# Combine MAX(IF formulas to find greatest value

Tags: worksheet-function

I have 3 Max(IF formulas which all work individually. They all have the same criteria (=A1) but the criteria range and the value range are on different sheets for each formula.

i.e. =MAX(IF(criteria_range=criteria,value_range))

I need to combine these formulas so that I get only the greatest result from all 3 data sets displayed in a single cell. Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: `Max(IF(),IF(),IF())`

Comment: Thank you.  That worked